# obs-studio not working

Tags: 20.04, obs-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, updated it, and then installed `obs-studio` from the repository, but I am getting this error:

```
obs studio failed to initialize video your gpu may not be supported
```

I tried to run it with `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs-studio` or `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs`, but still the same error message. I also tried other Nvidea drivers but it didn't work.

Is OBS not currently working with Ubuntu 20.04?

Here is the graphics card info:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Try vokoscreen. It should be better then obs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing obs from Ubuntu software center (snap version).

Answer (score 2):

You can also install it using `sudo snap install obs-studio` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Restart Ubuntu. This happens because the driver has been updated (nvidia) and it has not reloaded.