# Troubleshooting graphic driver issue to run OBS Studio (Intel i5 M520)

Tags: 20.04, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl, obs-studio

I recently installed [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com) under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop (a Lenovo Thinkpad T410). While I didn't encounter any issue during the installation, I am unable to run OBS Studio itself, as I keep running into the following error:

```
Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.
```

In order to provide you with all the necessary details, here is the complete console output of the `obs` command:

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/fr-FR.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/fr-FR.ini
info: Using preferred locale 'fr-FR'
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
info: CPU Speed: 1548.597MHz
info: Physical Cores: 2, Logical Cores: 4
info: Physical Memory: 3733MB Total, 228MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "20.04"
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.20.8
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_destroyed()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionGridMode_triggered()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_program_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_transitionRemove_clicked()
info: OBS 26.0.2 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 48000
    speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
error: X Error: GLXBadFBConfig, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 34, Serial: 29
error: Failed to create OpenGL context.
error: Failed to create context!
error: device_create (GL) failed
error: Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 2009,26 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 9,107 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 4,805 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 241,855 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 20,295 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 54,346 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0,672 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0,257 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 52,276 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0,129 ms, median=0,325 ms, max=15,866 ms, 99th percentile=15,866 ms, 100% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0,021 ms, median=0,042 ms, max=0,086 ms, 99th percentile=0,086 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25,215 ms, median=25,444 ms, max=40,983 ms, 64,4068% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 35,5932% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 178
```

After searching the issue, it appears my problem is that I have a too old OpenGL version (2.1). While my GPU (integrated; my CPU being Intel i5 M520) isn't cutting-edge, it doesn't seem to be too old for OBS Studio because I also installed the same program on my Windows 10 (as my laptop is a *dual boot*) and I had no issue running it to capture from my webcam or from an opened window.

However, I have a hard time finding out how I can upgrade my OpenGL version under Ubuntu 20.04. My best attempt was to get a more up-to-date version of the Mesa 3D library via the `kisak-mesa` PPA, but while it upgraded my version of Mesa, it didn't change the OpenGL version. Here is what I get when I run the `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` command:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.2.1 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

On a side note, I also had a look at the *Additional drivers* tab in *Softwares & Updates*, but this tab is completely empty in my case and doesn't suggest any driver that could improve my current situation.

What could I do to this fix ? [Another recent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237322/obs-studio-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04) suggests installing OBS Studio via snap, but despite trying that, I get the same issue as before.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on debian 10

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs`

Source: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/failed-to-initialize-video-your-gpu-may-not-be-supported-or-your-graphics-drivers-may-need-to-be-updated.86284/